# different css selection on same structure

Tags: css

I'm testing some css mixes in two wordpress themes. Im getting two different css selections on what seems the same html and css structure.

[image: code to compare]

On the image, the first part relates to an expected css selection beahviour: I have a div with a class of type "register-lesson". Than, inside I have a span element which is set by a "margin-bottom: 30px;" style. I expected this because this selection is more narrow than the other two bellow.

On the other hand, in the second part of the image, I dont get the same beahviour, although the html and the css classes seems the same. In this case, the "register-lesson" class type is the third choice, and consequently Im not getting the expected "margin-bottom: 30px;" applied to the span element.

Can someone explain me why this happens?

(im using firefox on the images)

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The second one is getting a `margin:0` applied from a `:last-child` rule. You need to change that rule or make the one with margin:30px beat the specificity of the other.

Quick and **dirrrrty** (and lazy) way is adding an `!important` to that rule.

Comment: But the first one also has that rule applied. However, it doesnt take precedence (look to the third possible css rule). Why this happens? The source css files are even the same. So, why the last-child rule is more specific in one case?

Comment: When I say the first one has the rule applied, is not what I want to say. I want to say that it has the possibility to apply that rule, but instead it applies the expected rule. Why not in the second?

Comment: can you provide a link so we can check the actual code?

Comment: sorry. it is not online.